# iOS TableView custom cell not showing anything

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to iOS and Swift and I'm trying to learn a little by creating a simple Todo app. The problem I came across is that no matter how I implement the code (followed multiple tutorials) and storyboards, the data doesn't show and the custom cells is not customized (it looks exactly how the default cells look even though I've customized it). I already connected my `delegate` and `dataSource`

**Edit:** I already assigned the reuse identifier

**TodosView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TodosView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var todosTable: UITableView!

    var todos: [Todo] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        todosTable.delegate = self
        todosTable.dataSource = self

        self.addTodo()
    }

    func addTodo() {
        let todo1 = Todo(text: "My first todo")
        let todo2 = Todo(text: "My second todo")

        todos = [todo1, todo2]
    }
}

extension TodosView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return todos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let todo = todos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodoCell") as! TodoCell

        cell.setTodo(todo: todo)

        return cell
    }
}
```

**TodoCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TodoCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var todoText: UILabel!

    func setTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todoText.text = todo.text
    }
}
```

**Todo.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Todo {
    var text: String
    var done: Bool

    init(text: String, done: Bool = false) {
        self.text = text
        self.done = done
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the class of the table view cell through Interface Builder.

Comment: @ElTomato I already did that

Comment: maybe you can try to reload your tableview at the end of the addTodo()  function.

Comment: Did you set a number of section? I can see you set rows but there is no section set in your code

Comment: Cross check that you have assigned the reuse Identifier to the TodoCell as "TodoCell" in your storyboard. Also if you have setup your custom row height, just validate if you have removed "Automatic" from "Row Height" in UITableView properties or in UITableViewCell, you have selected Custom.

Comment: I guess you forget to call todosTable.reloadData()

Comment: @SarabjitSinghthat wasn't it

Answer (score 6):

I succeeded in using your code to successfully generate your Todo rows (I did not `reloadData()` after calling `addTodo()`);

[image]

Having proven that your code does work, it leads me to believe that you have an issue somewhere in your Storyboard setup, more-so than you do in your code itself.  A few suggestions:

**Verify your custom cell is subclassed as a TodoCell**.  You can do this by clicking on your TodoCell in Interface Builder, and in the *Identity Inspector* tab, verify you have this set to TodoCell:

[image]

This is likely not the issue as your app would more than likely crash if your cells were not subclassed properly.

**Verify you have set the cell identifier in Interface Builder**.  Again, click on the TodoCell in Interface Builder, go to the *Attributes Inspector* tab, and verify identifier is set to TodoCell:

[image]

Also, do make sure that you've actually connected your tableView and todoText UILabel to your code.  I see you have @IBOutlets to these items, but if you were copying and pasting from a tutorial, it's possible you typed in the items and never actually connected them.  The gray circle next to your IBOutlet for both the tableView and UILabel should be filled in, like so:

[image]

If it's empty, you may not have a connection, which could explain the issue.  Again, I copied and pasted your code verbatim and set things per the above suggestions; I do not believe that `reloadData()` or setting the number of sections will help the issue (as your code did not have them and it's working on my end).

Comment: Checked all of those, and I have it exactly the same as you. I think I might need to restart the project from scratch and see if that works

Comment: "I do not believe that reloadData() or setting the number of sections will help the issue" , everytime you update the datasource you need to reload the tableivew to see the changes, the code is working at your end because you have addTodo()  in your viewDidLoad so tableview will reload after view did load will be called try to add addTodo() in your view did appear and let me know there is a need to reload the datasource or not, with no respect due.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableview after updating the datasource :-

```
func addTodo() {
    let todo1 = Todo(text: "My first todo")
    let todo2 = Todo(text: "My second todo")
    todos = [todo1, todo2]
    todosTable.reloadData()
}
```

**Edit**
I also noticed by looking at the JWC comment you didn't have the numberOfSection method implemented so you must also add the number of section delegate method.

Comment: that's the problem (just tried it), even if the array is initialized with data it won't show it in the table view. My problem is that the custom cells are not even created

Comment: did you assign the "TodoCell" identifier to your tableview cell in storyboard?

Comment: what did you use for TodoCell, Storyboard or xib?

Comment: `numberOfSection` is not necessary until you need more than one.

Comment: @dreamBegin I did assign the identifier, storyboard, and kamran is right because by default the table view has 1 section already so it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the data to `array` after creating the `tableView`.

Change this line :

```
var todos: [Todo] = []
```

to

```
var todos: [Todo]! {
    didSet {
        self.todosTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and in `numberOfRowsInSection` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard (todos != nil) else {
        return 0
    }
    return todos.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
func addTodo() {
   let todo1 = Todo(text: "My first todo")
   let todo2 = Todo(text: "My second todo")
   todos = [todo1, todo2]
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.todosTable.reloadData()
   }
}
```

This might help you

Comment: Reloading the data wasn't the problem, in fact, I still don't know what the problem was, I started the project from scratch and now it is working.